# jaxb2-basics and inheritance

Tags: xjc, jaxb2-basics

I am successfully using jaxb2-basics for inheritance support.  I am trying to add some more inheritance but cannot figure out how to do that in a specific situation.  I have this XSD fragment:

```
<xsd:complexType name="hbm-any-mapping">
    <xsd:element name="discriminator">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xsd:element name="column" type="orm:column" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xsd:element name="mapping" type="orm:hbm-any-discriminator-value-mapping" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:complexType>
```

In my XJC binding I had this originally, and it works:

```
<bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='hbm-any-mapping']">
    <inheritance:implements>...</inheritance:implements>
</bindings>

<bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='hbm-any-discriminator-value-mapping']">
    <inheritance:implements>...</inheritance:implements>
    <property name="CorrespondingEntityName"/>
    <bindings node=".//xsd:attribute[@name='value']">
       <property name="DiscriminatorValue"/>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Now I am trying to apply interfaces to the mapping for `discriminator` and its sub-nodes.  I tried this:

```
<bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='hbm-any-mapping']">
    <inheritance:implements>...</inheritance:implements>

    <bindings node=".//xsd:element[@name='discriminator']">
        <inheritance:implements>...</inheritance:implements>

        <bindings node=".//xsd:element[@name='mapping']">
            <inheritance:implements>...</inheritance:implements>
            <property name="valueMappings"/>
        </bindings>

    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

But that does not work.  I don't get an error, but the inheritance is not applied for discriminator nor is the property naming for mapping.

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I broke them out into separate, named complexType definitions and applied the inheritance by selecting those complexTypes.  It works.